# Convert basic Pine script strategy to study for creating alerts

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm want to convert a simple TradingView script "ChannelBreakOutStrategy" to study script,  anyone can help me ?

Actually, i have differences with plotshape strategy and study, and i don't understand why.

```
//@version=4
strategy("ChannelBreakOutStrategy Julien", overlay=true)
length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, minval=1, maxval=1000, defval=5)

upBound = highest(high, length)
downBound = lowest(low, length)

if (not na(close[length]))
    strategy.entry("ChBrkLE", strategy.long, stop=upBound + syminfo.mintick, comment="Achat")
    strategy.entry("ChBrkSE", strategy.short, stop=downBound - syminfo.mintick, comment="Vente")
```

I have  to try convert with this simple conversion, with fail :

```
//@version=4
study("Alert convert Julien", overlay=true)
length = input(title="Length", type=input.integer, minval=1, maxval=1000, defval=10)

upBound = highest(high, length)
downBound = lowest(low, length)

short_cond = close[length] < downBound
long_cond = close[length] > upBound

plotshape(short_cond, title="vente", style=shape.triangledown, color=color.red)
plotshape(long_cond, title="achat", style=shape.triangleup, color=color.green)

alertcondition(short_cond or long_cond, title='Vente ou achat', message='Vente ou achat - Red and blue have crossed!')

plot(close)
```

The screenshot to see difference "Vente" = Strategy, and "Test Vente" = Study test :

[Démo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cse7W.jpg)

Thank you !

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Hey Baris, i have differences to convert strategy to study, plotshape (entrypoint) have so many differences.